# How to Toggle between bootstrap collapse contain data from server

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap-4, toggle

I have this collapse in my Laravel project using data from database :-

```
<div class="col col-md-5">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header text-right">
            <h4>{{__('home.course_card')}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

            <div id="accordion" >
                <div class="card">
                    @foreach ($mysection as $section)
                    <?php $sec_name='home.sec'.$section->section_name ;
                    $collaps_count++;
                    ?>
                        <div class="w-100 card-header py-0 px-0" id="" style="border: none">
                            
                            <button class=" btn w-100 text-right bg-light " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" >
                                <h5 class="">{{__($sec_name)}}</div></h5>
                            </button>
                           
                        </div>
                        <div style="height:5px"></div>
                    @foreach ($course->Lession as $lession)
                    @if ($section->section_name == $lession->section_name)
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse <?php if($collaps_count == 1) echo 
  'show'?>" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="flex-row d-flex justify-content-between text-right mx-auto 
  w-100 py-2">
                                    <div>- {{$lession->$less_lang}}</div>
                                    @if ($lession->id==$order->lession_id)
                                        <div class="text-left ml-2"><i class="material-icons" 
  style="color:green">visibility</i></div>
                                    @else
                                        <div class="text-left ml-2"><i class="material-icons" 
  style="color:grey">visibility</i></div>
                                    @endif                                         
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif    
                    @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I have more than two collapse data the switch between them not work correctly ,when I press in first one both second and third collapse open,
How can I make toggle between many collapse depend on data from server?

Answer (score 1):

I solved first issue which happened as a reason of same id name of collapse ,therefore I used this code to change id names :

```
  $collaps_count++;
  $nf = new NumberFormatter("en", NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
  $numbers_name=$nf->format($collaps_count);
  $numbers_name=ucfirst($numbers_name);
  $collapse_id='collapse'.$numbers_name;
  $heading='heading'.$numbers_name;
```